# Steps to display a html element close to a pinpoint

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I know how to place markers with and all the attributes seem allright

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : latlng,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        shadow: icon_shadow,
        title : name
    });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    jQuery('#info').fadeIn();
  });
```

How can I position the info box so it's close to the pinpoint?
Site's where I've seen this in action all seemed to use api v2.

Comment: probably you can use jquery offset and get the top and left and use those as reference.

Comment: @siri, how do i get the top/left offset from the marker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your google map as var map, and your marker named marker

```
emptyoverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
emptyoverlay.draw = function() {};
emptyoverlay.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function(){
        //Getting the x/y positions
        var absPos  = emptyoverlay.getProjection().fromLatLngToContainerPixel(this.getPosition());
        absPos.x += 10; // Now we have it we can shift around
        absPos.y += -10; // Where the box shows up
        console.log(absPos);
        //jQuery magic starts here
        jQuery('#message').show().html('anything you want').css({left: absPos.x, top: absPos.y});
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout',function(){
        jQuery('#message').hide();
});
```